# GCSE logarithmic problem - don't know base

Tags: logarithms

There's a question in my iGCSE textbook that I don't know how to answer. I HAVE TRIED TO ANSWER IT! The question is: $$log(x)=\frac{10-x}{20}$$
I don't know what the base for the $log()$ is. Putting this question into Wolfram Alpha or other equation solvers doesn't work.

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is either the natural logarithm and hence has base $e$ or the base $10$ logarithm. Either logarithms can be represented by the symbol $\log{(x)}$ and it cannot be determined without other contextual information.

Although, it is standard in GCSE problems that $\ln{(x)}$ means the natural logarithm (base $e$) and $\log{(x)}$ means the base $10$ logarithm.

Although, the solution to this equation can only be found by using numerical methods (a calculator) so I do not think it would be printed as written for iGCSE students.

Comment: Minor note/addition: $\log_2(x)$ is apparently also the common interpretation of $\log(x)$ in computer science. To my understanding, what $\log(x)$ means w.r.t. its base is basically determined entirely by what is most commonly used in the relevant field/context. I personally hate that convention, but such is life.

Answer (score 2):

For the solution you can use the LambertW function:
$$x={{\rm e}^{-{\rm W} \left(1/20\,{{\rm e}^{1/2}}\right)+1/2}}$$

Comment: The OP states that the question is intended for iGCSE students (14-17 years old) - I don't think this is the intended solution.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. @PeterForeman is right, this is too complicated for iGCSE students. The answer was  to draw the function f(x) = log (x) and then to draw the line g(x) = (10-x)/20.

Comment: Acquiring more knowledge does not harm.